# String formatting in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've to format a name according the system setting. Available setting values are

- Last, Prefix First, Middle, Suffix
- Last, First, Middle, Suffix
- Last, Prefix First, Suffix
- Last, First, Suffix
- First Middle Last Suffix
- First Middle Last
- First Last Suffix
- First Last
- Prefix First Middle Last
- Prefix First Middle Last Suffix
- Prefix First Last
- Prefix First Last Suffix

I've come up with following without using switch case.

```
    DECLARE @fullname NVARCHAR(225),
            @LastName NVARCHAR(50),
            @FirstName NVARCHAR(50),
            @MiddleName NVARCHAR(50),
            @Prefix NVARCHAR(32),
            @Suffix NVARCHAR(32)

    SET @fullname = 'Last, Prefix First, Middle, Suffix' -- this would be pulled from db

    SELECT @LastName = 'Last',  @FirstName= 'First', @MiddleName= 'M', @Prefix= 'Mr.', @Suffix = 'MD' -- this would be pulled from db

    SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Last', COALESCE((' ' + @LastName), ' [NA]'));
    SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'First', COALESCE((' ' + @FirstName), ' [NA]'));
    SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Middle', COALESCE((' ' + @MiddleName), ''));
    SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Prefix', COALESCE((' ' + @Prefix), ''));
    SET @fullname = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(@fullname, N'Suffix', COALESCE((' ' + @Suffix), ''))));

    WHILE RIGHT(@fullname, 1)=','
    BEGIN
        SELECT @fullname=RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@fullname, 1, LEN(@fullname)-1))
    END

    SELECT @fullname
```

MiddleName, Prefix and Suffix are nullable fields.
Could there be a better way to do this?

Comment: Why are you trying to do it in [T]SQL? SQL, after all, is meant for data manipulation, not presentation.

Comment: Presuming you have a presentation layer (some web scripting language or an application, etc.) and this isn't being ran as some one-off query to export to csv or so, @BrankoDimitrijevic is exactly right.  You should be pulling back Last, Prefix, First, Middle, and Suffix and dealing with these pieces of information within the application itself, not on the SQL side.  Wherever possible, you're best off avoiding doing any sort of data formatting on the SQL side, as not only is it normally clunky, but it's also not a best practice.

Comment: it would be used by sps that export data out. Also by SSRS reports and couple other non-C# things.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you are using extra spaces.  You already have the spaces in the pattern:

```
SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Last', COALESCE(@LastName, ' [NA]'));
SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'First', COALESCE(@FirstName, ' [NA]'));
SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Middle', COALESCE(@MiddleName, ''));
SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, N'Prefix', COALESCE(@Prefix, ''));
```

Then the trim is not necessary.  If you are concerned about a name like "Kate Middleton" interfering, then I would suggest setting up the pattern as:

```
SET @fullname = '[Last], [Prefix] [First], [Middle], [Suffix]' ;
```

If you cannot format it in the database, then format it before you use it:

```
SET @fullname = REPLACE(@fullname, 'Last', '[Last]');
. . .
```

This will prevent collisions between name elements and real names.

Comment: Thanks. Removed the extra spaces. THe trim is necessary when middle, prefix or suffix are null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to a UDF, here is a dramatically modifed function that may be used to "Tokenize" virtually any record or string.

The token would be, for example `[[First_Name]]`.

Now, any residual `[[TOKENS]]` or extra/repeating spaces would be removed (Thanks to Gordon's brilliant trick)

Just one caveat:  The Field Names must match the Token (or visa-versa)/

The parameters are:

1. Row Data as XML Raw  - Can be as simple as `(Select A.* for XML Raw)`
2. The Desired Pattern  - `[[Last_Name]], [[First_Name]] [[Middle]]`
3. Default Value for missing values - `[NA]` or any string

Performance is respectable.  For example 10,000 records in 1.424 seconds

**Example or [dbFiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b84623cb144f40bcee755622d8894538)**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,[First] varchar(50),[Last] varchar(50),[Middle] varchar(25),[Suffix] varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
(1,'John','Smith','James','Jr.'),
(2,'Jane','Doe','',null)

Declare @Pattern varchar(max) = '[[Last]], [[First]] [[Middle]] [[Suffix]]'

Select A.ID
      ,Formatted = [dbo].[udf-Str-Tokenize](B.XMLData,@Pattern,'[NA]')
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (values ((Select A.* for XML Raw)) ) B(XMLData)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Formatted
1   Smith, John James Jr.
2   Doe, Jane [NA]
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Tokenize](@XML xml,@Pattern varchar(max),@Default varchar(100))
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Select @Pattern = Replace(@Pattern,Item,Value)
     From (
            Select Item   = '[['+attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')+']]'
                  ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
             From  @XML.nodes('/row') as xn(n)
             Cross Apply xn.n.nodes('./@*') AS xa(attr)
            Union All
            Select Item  = left(Item,charindex(']]',Item)+1)
                  ,Value = @Default 
             From (
                    Select Item  = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(@Pattern,'[[','||[['),'||','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                  ) P 
             Where charindex('[[',Item)>0 and charindex(']]',Item)>0
          ) A 

    Return ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(@Pattern,' ','><'),'<>',''),'><',' ')))
End
```

> **EDIT - No Need for CROSS APPLY**

```
Select ID
      ,Formatted = [dbo].[udf-Str-Tokenize]((Select A.* for XML Raw),@Pattern,' ')
 From  @YourTable A
```